# Creating .NET Maui release version ended with error

Tags: visual-studio, maui

I want to create an Android release version of my .NET MAUI program. Unfortunately, the process always ends with the error message:

*C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.46\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2361,2): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2. [C:\Projects\MauiTest.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-android]*

The program is relatively large and comprises 20 pages.
I tried with Multidex enabled or switched between Android API 30 and 33. It showed no change.
What else can I do?

Comment: Can your app be built successfully?

Comment: Yes, a signed apk file will be created. But when I try to install it on my Samsung phone, I get the message:
The app was not installed because the package appears to be invalid.

Comment: What's the version of your phone? Have you tried to install the apk file to other devices?

Comment: If you’re targeting Android 12 or higher, you need to add attribute `Exported= true`  or `Exported= false`  explicitly  for each `activity`, `service`, and `receiver`.

Comment: My Android version is 13. 
Where do I have to set the "Exported" flag? Is my app no longer backwards compatible?
I added the flag in the 'MainActivity.cs' file on the [Activity... line. But with the same negative result.
About half a year ago, when my program was much smaller, it worked. I didn't get an error message then.

Comment: Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: Thanks for the query. Meanwhile I revised the .csproj file and it works now. Many thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply but I was on vacation.
I have defined the PropertyGroup for the Android Release as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-android|AnyCPU'">
    <Debugger>Xamarin</Debugger>
    <AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>
    <AndroidEnableMultiDex>False</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyStore>xxx.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>xxxkey</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
    <AndroidSigningKeyPass>MyPassword</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass>MyPassword</AndroidSigningStorePass>
    <AndroidLinkResources>false</AndroidLinkResources>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then it worked.

Comment: Please mark it as answered so that it will help others who have similar problem.  Thanks in advance. :)